# Ruby 1.9 and Sass encoding issues. (from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)

Tags: ruby, encoding, sass

I recently upgraded to Ruby 1.9 and I can no longer compile anything with Sass.

I've seen solutions that state if I place

```
 @charset "utf-8";
```

at the top of my .sccs file, it will fix it. However I'm still getting an error. Here's the full traceback

I've also tried removing any non-ascii characters from my CSS file, creating a new one, etc. It just won't compile. Any tips?

Traceback:

> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>
> /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:496:in `encode': transcoding not supported (from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8) (ArgumentError)
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:496:in `_enc'
>       from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:515:in`rescue in block (1 levels) in '
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:508:in `block (1 levels) in '
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:472:in `yield'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:472:in `default'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:472:in `block in check_sass_encoding'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:471:in `each'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:471:in `find'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/util.rb:471:in `check_sass_encoding'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:349:in `check_encoding!'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:316:in `_to_tree'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:291:in `_render'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/engine.rb:238:in `render'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:319:in `update_stylesheet'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:169:in `block in update_stylesheets'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:167:in `each'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:167:in `update_stylesheets'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:214:in `watch'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/plugin.rb:111:in `method_missing'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:408:in `watch_or_update'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:294:in `process_result'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/gems/sass-3.1.1/bin/sass:8:in `'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/bin/sass:19:in `load'
>
> from /home/webdev/.gem/repository/bin/sass:19:in `'

Comment: Funny, your problem was the answer to my problem :) That is I needed to specify UTF-8 as encoding which seems to work in latest sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly the core of the issue, but it seems there were some problems with Ruby 1.9.0 (the version available on apt for this Ubuntu box) and encoding.

To solve the issue, I used https://rvm.io which is a helper to download and compile Ruby from Git, giving me the latest version. After running this, sass compiles fine and everything is swell.

Answer (score 11):

To complete [@nex3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970830/893211) you can

Open the `config.rb` file and add:

```
Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"
```

Comment: and where do you find this file on mac?

Comment: This answer solved my issue immediately. SASS seemed to stop compiling after I ran CSS Comb on it but is now fully working again following this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like somehow your Ruby environment is set up to load the Sass source code as `ASCII-8BIT`, a.k.a. `BINARY`. This is probably because you're either passing the `-Kn` flag to the Ruby process, or setting `Encoding.default_external` to `Encoding::BINARY` somewhere in your code before Sass is loaded. Undo this, and Sass should work.

Comment: Thanks for the great information, however how do I adjust this? I am simply calling the Sass binary through the command line. The locale set in the shell is utf-8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the solution was not apparent: Elena Pogorelova of Jet Brains [explained in this post that non-ASCII characters in your files route may break SASS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000082570-SCSS-Encoding-CompatibilityError-incompatible-character-encodings-CP850-and-UTF-8), as was in my case.

`users/xxxx/projects/chilediseño/cms/scss` **(ñ)**

I just had to eliminate the (ñ) in the name above and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably obvious, but are you sure your Sass file is UTF-8 encoded? Any decent text editor will let you convert encodings.

Comment: Using vim, it reports utf-8 with :language. If I set :set encoding=utf-8, still no luck.