# CSS pseudo element ▼ becomes gibberish in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-element

I'm using the ▼ character as the content of my pseudo element:

```
a:after {
    content: '▼';
}
```

This works great in all modern (read: non-IE) browsers:

[image: Here you see that it's working correctly in modern browsers]

but in IE(9), I just get gibberish instead:

[image: Here you see that it's broken in IE(9)]

---

I guess this has something to do with the character encoding, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried `content: '\9660';`? Is your CSS file and web page using the same char set? Do you have a `@charset` in your CSS different to its MIME type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that both your page and your stylesheet are encoded and served as UTF-8. Most editors should be able to tell you the encoding of any open file.

You can also opt to use the Unicode sequence `\9660` instead, but again you need to ensure that your documents are encoded as UTF-8 otherwise it may not work correctly either:

```
a:after {
    content: '\9660';
}
```

Or if your stylesheet has a `@charset` rule, it needs to point to UTF-8:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Note that [`@charset` rules need to appear at the very beginning of a stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#charset); in `@import`ed files I believe this should not be an issue, but seeing as Sass actually combines files together that are linked by `@import` rules during compilation, this will cause errors. For Sass/SCSS, you'll need to place the `@charset` rule at the beginning of your master stylesheet.

Comment: I'm using SASS, and I just realized that they're adding `@charset "IBM437";` to the beginning of my CSS file. Anything I can do about it?

Comment: @MegaHit: Change it to `@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: Are you saying that I have to change it after EVERY time I save my SASS file? Is there no way to stop SASS from adding that in there?

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sass-lang/CGGgPWAbUKM SASS is adding it like that because your input file is encoded in IBM437; you should change your input file to be UTF-8.

Comment: @MegaHit: It shouldn't try to change that line if you have one within your stylesheet. Can't say for sure as I don't use Sass myself though, but it shouldn't misbehave...

Comment: @Domenic - I've double and triple checked, but my `.scss` file is definitely encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: @BoltClock - Actually, it does. I explicitly set `@charset "UTF-8";` at the top of my `.scss` file, but that didn't make it into my `.css` file, and I got `@charset "IBM437";` instead.

Comment: @MegaHit Hmm. Perhaps relevant, if you're using Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967626/ruby-1-9-and-sass-encoding-issues-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8

Comment: OK, I got it to work. I had `@charset "UTF-8";` set in my `head.scss` file, which I had then `@import`ed into my main `scss` file (SASS actually pulls it into the file). Since that didn't work, I just added the `@charset "UTF-8";` to the main file before any `@import`s, and it worked. You should update your answer with this info, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @BoltClock's answer, be sure to [send appropriate headers from your server](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset), and, perhaps just for good measure, add a `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also by adding a background image to your menu.

```
 a{background:url("http://pathtoyourimage/");}
```