# Stylesheet not loading in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, stylesheet, mozilla

I'm stumped. Working on a site that isn't loading properly in FireFox. It loads great in Chrome and even IE, but for some reason the stylesheet isn't loading in FireFox.

The site: http://gregsonaccounting.com

I'm using html5 code and have used the basic resets and such from html5 Boiler Plate. Not sure if the problem is in my html or CSS.

Any insight is *extremely* helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgregsonaccounting.com%2F often helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes from style.css which begins by `@charset "IBM437"`
Replace it with `@charset "UTF-8";` and it will be better !

It seams this charset IBM437 is auto added by SASS:

[CSS pseudo element ▼ becomes gibberish in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759955/css-pseudo-element-becomes-gibberish-in-ie)

Comment: Any idea of how to keep SASS from adding IBM437? When I recompile my stylesheet now from SASS it still reverts to the problematic IBM437. Perhaps there's a way to tell it to use UTF-8 in the Config.rb file?

Comment: It seems if the source file is both UTF-8 and if @charset "UTF-8"; is the very first line then sass gets it right.

Answer (score 4):

A stylesheet should be defined in the format;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

You may also include `media` attribute, that they specify how a document is to be presented on different media: on the screen, on paper, with a speech synthesizer, with a braille device, etc.

In your page, it is;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />//Here is the problem
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

So that line may be modified like;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: since HTML5 it is not anymore necessary to specify `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

My CSS code worked well on **Chrome**, but it kept **crashing on IE and Firefox**. Then i found out the problem was in a badly preprocessed CSS.

**Just copy paste your CSS to http://csslint.net/** and if you **get any error**, just fix it and you are good :)

Worth trying!

Answer (score -1):

insert this inside your html documents. I am not writing in code just giving u the key words so you know and can put it in.

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"

it works so make sure you have this correctly or else your html document will not load with your stylesheet. best of luck to you and keep working brah.