# Why my HTML list is not displaying in Firefox for mobiles?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobiles v 1.4.2. Following is my code from my page.

#### HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">
  <li><a href="#" >Bienes Ra&iacute;ces en San Jos&eacute;</a></li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
.ui-listview li 
{ 
   margin: 10px !important;
   border-radius: 5px !important;
   border-left:1px solid !important;
   border-right:1px solid;
   background-color: #C0DAE7;
}

.ui-listview li:hover 
{    
   background-color: #EDF6FA;
}

.ui-listview 
{
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  height:40px;
}
```

When page first loads on mobile it is not taking any change in css like `background-color` or `border`. If it refreshed two or three times then it worked.

**Note:** it is not working in Firefox for mobiles.

what could be the cause/reason behind this behavior. Please advise.

Comment: Can you check how you load the stylesheets --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663889/stylesheet-not-loading-in-mozilla-firefox

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple reasons why the changes aren't showing.

1. Not all browsers interpret html the same way, and can calculate things like borders, margins, padding etc. differently than you might expect.
2. The browser has not detected a change in the html because you have only changed the data in the .css and thus the html has not changed; so a it may think a cached version will suffice.
3. You accidentally saved the new css file in the wrong spot via ftp so the changes you think you made don't show because it is looking at the old file which hasn't changed. (this has happened to me)
4. The server simply hasn't finished saving/overwriting the old file, and takes a minute to finish the operation; which would also explain the lag in changes showing up.

Another thing I do sometimes is pop over to the [w3schools HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and the [w3schools CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and let them take a quick peek at my code to make sure I haven't accidentally missed anything; because misplaced tags and other small error can cause a **big** difference in your output.

Comment: realistically you just have to be patient. sometimes the changes don't show up right away; that's just the way it is. depends on the server, latency, whether you tried to save the file when it was being accessed - which happens a lot if you get trigger happy with hot-keys like me and love constantly saving the code in the text-editor, and then quickly switching back to the webpage and repeatedly hitting refresh because I'm excited to see the changes..

Comment: I added more to my answer as well

Comment: open the debug console and look at the css

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes cache is the reason for such kind of behavior. Press alt+ctrl+Delete to clear the cache of the browser and check it.. Hope this will works..